# Is it possible via CSS 3 to set the color of text in an element using the text content?

Tags: css

Okay, so this is more of a question that has lots of solutions that are not CSS, but I'm looking for doing this more from a theoretical perspective. I have an application for it, but its not worth coding it out in any other way.

### The (Fun) Question

How do you color the text of an element using the text of the element? I have an element, all on it's own, which will contain a hex value for a color, and I want the text to be that color, but I want to do it only using CSS (likely only can be done using CSS 3).

#### Sample HTML

```html
<div class="color_contents">#0000FF</div>
```

So, I've tried to use the `attr()` with no success, but I'm not sure I'm using the right contents (I've tried `text`, `textContent`, and `innerText` to no avail). Doesn't need to be cross-browser, but just a way to accomplish it.

Comment: I can, but am looking for a pure CSS solution. Again, there are a lot of ways to actually accomplish this, but I want to do it using only CSS.

Comment: @Valchris I'm guessing that would count as a solution that is not CSS.

Comment: I don't think this is possible as CSS has no way to see the content of the element it's targeting.

Comment: @KyleSevenoaks This might be the case. But I was curious if there were a method to do so via something like the `attr()` value or something. And it used to have the `:contains()` pseudo-selector, so I figured it might not be completely out of the question

Comment: 7 days isn't a lot of time for "future implementations" ;)

Comment: Anyway, does the bounty solution have to work with your exact sample HTML? Or to what extent may the markup be modified?

Comment: The markup may be modified as much as you want, as long as the solution still styles based on the content (not on an attribute based on the content, unless you can get it to work automatically without javascript or something). Also, 7 days is unfortunately what you get with a bounty, so not much I could do lol

Comment: Well, a draft of CSS 4 selectors has been published, and the `:contains` selector is absent. I think we can say that 'future implementations' is out as well, and no hack, so I'm marking best, and awarding bounty. Turns out, it's not possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, there is no way to use CSS to access an element's text content, not even with the CSS3 modules available today.

Regarding this:

> So, I've tried to use the `attr()` with no success, but I'm not sure I'm using the right contents (I've tried `text`, `textContent`, and `innerText` to no avail). Doesn't need to be cross-browser, but just a way to accomplish it.

`attr()` only looks at element attributes (`foo="bar"`). Since text content isn't an attribute of an HTML element (despite being a member of the corresponding DOM object), you can't query for it using that function.

There isn't a similar function for accessing an element's text content.

Comment: Maybe if the content is generated by OP, he could use `<div data-color="#0000FF">#0000FF</div>` and use progressive enhancement to set the color with `[data-color]{ color: attr(data-color, color); }`.

Comment: You are right, I edited the comment now. I read `The following features are at-risk and may be dropped during the CR period: ‘vh’, ‘vw’, ‘vm’, ‘fr’, ‘gr’, ‘cycle()’, ‘attr()’.` in http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#status , but when I was editing to add a source I also found: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#attr and so decided to remove that.

Comment: You are correct in all of your post so a +1. My attempts at using `attr()` were really to try and see if I could 'hack' my way to getting the text content. My question is really in full realization of what is mentioned, but is kind of a sort of thought experiment/hack content to see if someone can get to the text content of an element using some creative CSS. For example, I also tried `content: inherit;` to no avail, and I think that is a more useful use case.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this.  It's a bit hacky, but all CSS

```css
div.color_0000FF:before{
    color:#0000FF;
    content: "#0000FF";
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="color_0000FF"></div>
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/s8vLy/

Comment: Yes, I'm aware I could use classes and content. But the code inside will be a random (to me at least) hex string, so I can't/don't want to code for all cases. This is also meant to be a CSS challenge more than anything, and I'll bounty it when I can.

Comment: Though, in theory, you could use `div[class^=color_]` as the selector, but then you run into a similar issue.

Answer (score 1):

The content/attr CSS properties can only be used with `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements.

CSS3 will support `attr` access from other properties, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/attr.

However when/if CSS3 attr goes live, you will still not be able to acces the "contents" of a element from CSS, simply because thats not what CSS is designed for.

Bottom line, use javascript :)