# Are there other sequences browsers interpret as HTML special characters?

Tags: php, html, security, xss

In HTML, there are several special characters `< > & ' "` which have significance to the DOM parser. These are the characters the popular functions such as PHP's [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) convert to HTML entities so they don't accidentally trigger something when parsed.

> The translations performed are:
>
> - '&' (ampersand) becomes `&amp;`
> - `"` (double quote) becomes `&quot;`
>     when ENT_NOQUOTES is not set.
> - `'` (single quote) becomes `&#039;` only
>     when ENT_QUOTES is set.
> - '<' (less than) becomes `&lt;`
> - '>' (greater than) becomes `&gt;`

However, I remember that in older browsers like IE6, there were also *other byte sequences* that caused the browser's DOM parser to [interpret content as HTML](http://ha.ckers.org/xss.html).

**Is this still a problem today? If you filter these 5 alone is that enough to prevent XSS?**

For example, here are all the *known*  combinations of the character "<" in HTML and JavaScript (in UTF-8).

```
<
%3C
&lt
&lt;
&LT
&LT;
&#60
&#060
&#0060
&#00060
&#000060
&#0000060
&#60;
&#060;
&#0060;
&#00060;
&#000060;
&#0000060;
&#x3c
&#x03c
&#x003c
&#x0003c
&#x00003c
&#x000003c
&#x3c;
&#x03c;
&#x003c;
&#x0003c;
&#x00003c;
&#x000003c;
&#X3c
&#X03c
&#X003c
&#X0003c
&#X00003c
&#X000003c
&#X3c;
&#X03c;
&#X003c;
&#X0003c;
&#X00003c;
&#X000003c;
&#x3C
&#x03C
&#x003C
&#x0003C
&#x00003C
&#x000003C
&#x3C;
&#x03C;
&#x003C;
&#x0003C;
&#x00003C;
&#x000003C;
&#X3C
&#X03C
&#X003C
&#X0003C
&#X00003C
&#X000003C
&#X3C;
&#X03C;
&#X003C;
&#X0003C;
&#X00003C;
&#X000003C;
\x3c
\x3C
\u003c
\u003C
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. I actually looked into this when I was researching using CSS and attributes to automatically assign styles based on content ([my question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7829397/422184)), and the short answer is no. Modern browsers do not allow 'byte sequences' to be used as HTML. I use 'byte sequences' lightly because the most at risk code does not use byte encoded values.

The examples listed on the XSS site are about using attributes and having the javascript interpreted as a string that would need execution. But also listed is things like `&{alert('XSS')}` which runs the code within the brackets, and that code does not work in modern browsers.

But to answer your second question, no, filtering those 5 is not enough to **prevent** an XSS attack. Throw your code through the PHP HTML special characters code always but there a [hundreds of byte codes that can be used](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references) and you won't really be able to guarantee anything. Sending it through a PHP filter (especially `htmlentities()`) will give you the exact text entered when you output it to HTML (IE `&laquo;` instead of «). That said, in most cases, depending your usage, using `htmlspecialchars` is enough to cover *most* attacks. Depends on how you will be using the input, but for the most part it will be safe.

XSS is a tricky thing to account for. A general good rule is always filter everything that a user will enter. And use white-listing instead of black-listing. What your talking about here would be black-listing these values, when it is always safer to assume your users are malicious and only allow certain things.

Comment: Netscape was the last browser I found with documentation that this worked actually, though I think it worked in IE 5 and a few others as well, just wasn't quite as well documented. But yes, modern browsers went away from being able to do that, probably for a few reasons (security, separation of content and action, etc).

Comment: Well, in my case I need to support as many characters as possible (especially unicode) so I'm trying to find out what to block since I can't understand almost all of the unicode space. Luckily, to my knowledge only the small ASCII space contains the dangerous stuff - I only wonder if the depths of unicode hold some things that might *help* trigger other bytes. (`preg_match_all('/\p{L}+/u', $str, $arr)`). I need to allow discussion of dangerous sequences also - so I don't want to remove everything suspicious.

Comment: @xeoncross if you are using the input as straight text input output and not running it through evals you should be fine with the php method listed. Other attacks could come from Unicode exploits like overloading a buffer but if you are straight outputting it, that would be a browser exploit and wouldn't necessarily be something you could catch easily. Best you could do is blacklist any known exploitable characters, and I don't know any off the top of my head

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example:

`<button onclick="confirm('Are you sure you want to delete &#39;);alert(&#39;xss')>`

Here the attackers input is what comes after "delete" and before ')>

This escaping will not work in this case, because we escaped for the wrong context.

In short xss prevention means escaping for the given context. In the above example we are in a javascript context within a HTML attribute context. See the OWASP XSS prevention cheat sheet.

Answer (score 1):

It suffices to escape text in HTML, but there are contexts in HTML where even text is dangerous:

- don't allow users to create arbitrary URLs (in `<a>`, `<img>`, etc.), as they can insert `javascript:` or many variations of it. Whitelist only `^https?://`.
- HTML-escaping doesn't suffice in `<script>` (it use entity-escaping anyway) or in attributes that execute a script (`onclick`, etc). For those you need `json_encode()`.